# Why am I getting Runtime errors for substring - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 10

Tags: java, text-parsing

I want to be able to use the substring method or if you guys have a better suggestion, on how to take numbers from a text file containing some info and being able to divide *num2* by 100 and multiply *num1* by *num2*.  I would like some insight on how to properly use the substring method.

This is what I have so far, although its not the full code(I got the other parts to work), I'd still appreciate if someone can help please.
also I am using one arraylist.

Text sample:

```
1 : 4.74 (93 % pa)

2 : 1.03 (92 % pa)

3 : 2.95 (99 % pa)

4 : 5.18 (61 % pa)

5 : 5.50 (81 % pa)

6 : 3.24 (55 % pa)

7 : 3.66 (64 % pa)

8 : 3.44 (98 % pa)

9 : 2.36 (76 % pa)

10 : 1.78 (94 % pa)
```

**edit:** Numbers are the decimal and percentage

**edit2:** Duh

**edit3:** Trying to solve this (Read this if you want to make it easier to understand what I am asking) http://csta.villanova.edu:8080/bitstream/2378/323/1/Forestry.html

```
case "Y": {

        try {
            FileReader text = new FileReader(mu + ".txt");
            Scanner file = new Scanner(text);

            //now read the file line by line...
            int lineNum = 0;
            while (file.hasNextLine()) {
                String num1 = file.nextLine();
                String num2 = file.nextLine();
                String year1 = "";
                num1 = year1.substring(4,9);
                String year2 = "";
                num2 = year2.substring(10,13);

                try {
                    double nnum1 = Double.valueOf(num1.trim()).doubleValue();
                    double nnum2 = Double.valueOf(num2.trim()).doubleValue();
                        nnum2 /= 100;
                    nnum1 *= nnum2;
                } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                     System.out.println("NumberFormatException: " + nfe.getMessage());
                }

                if(lineNum == projekt.size()) { 
                    num1 = year1.substring(5,10);
                    num2 = year2.substring(11,14);
                    try {
                        double nnum3 = Double.valueOf(num1.trim()).doubleValue();
                        double nnum4 = Double.valueOf(num2.trim()).doubleValue();
                            nnum4 /= 100;
                            nnum3 *= nnum4;
                    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                         System.out.println("NumberFormatException: " + nfe.getMessage());
                    }

                }
                lineNum++;
            }
            file.close();
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) { 
            System.out.println("Nope");
        }
        //ecree = new PrintWriter(mu + ".txt");
        //height + height * percentage 
        // use substring to grab percentage from file
        // remember to divide the percentage by 100 to show
    }
    break;
```

Comment: See the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-), the answer is there.

Comment: You need to check your string length always. It seems, while you iterate, there is an empty line, so runtime exception is thrown

Comment: The step-by-step debugger is your friend.

Comment: I think in your program you define year1 and year2 as an empty strings and then define num1 and num2 as their substrings. I believe you meant the other way.

Comment: @Valijon I think I failed to mention that it uses an array list to store the numbers in the text file, and its year1 and year2?

Comment: @AhmadGhadiri so I had it mixed? I'll check thank you guys for responding so quickly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) Not sure what the Scanner class does but it seems that you read 2 lines at once.
                while (file.hasNextLine()) 
                {
                    String num1 = file.nextLine();
                    String num2 = file.nextLine();

b) You should not overwrite your data: you read text into num1 but you assign a part of the empty string (year1) to it which for sure produces an index out of bounds exception:
                    String num1 = file.nextLine();
                    String year1 = "";
                    num1 = year1.substring(4,9);

you mean maybe

```
                String num1 = file.nextLine();
                String year1 = num1.substring(4,9);
```

c) you should be using java pattern matching in order to have a more generic approach (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

```
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\s*\\:\\s*(\\d+\\.\\d*)\\s*\\((d+).+");
                String num1 = file.nextLine();
                String year1 = o.match(num1.trim());
```

Comment: Wow thanks, I'm really new to programming but I didn't know this existed thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling you are calling `substring` on the wrong variables.

```
                String year1 = "";
                num1 = year1.substring(4,9);
                String year2 = "";
                num2 = year2.substring(10,13);
```

You set year1 to "" then try to set num1 to a substring of "".

Looks like you want it the other way around.

Comment: Thanks for the help, althought I ran into some more problems haha. Q_Q. _NumberFormatException: For input string: "1 : 4.74 (93 % pa)"_